# google world map chart

Tags: google-visualization

http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=map:fixed=?,?,?,?&chs=550x350

how do you display the world map in the new version above like in the old one below?

the old version was that you just have to set chtm=world

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=bg,s,EAF7FE&chs=440x220&cht=t&chco=FFFFFF,FF0000,FFFF00,00FF00&chd=t:-1&chtm=world

thanks

Comment: I get a 400 error for both links.

Comment: @yoda: Corrected the second link. There was a space in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=map:fixed=-60,0,80,-35&chs=600x350